# MATLAB: Plotting a scatter plot with 3 matrices of different dimensions

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I've been given a 1x16 matrix of temperature and a 1 x 21 matrix of humidity.
On top of that I have a 21x16 matrix of 0's and 1's where 0's are uncomfortable temp-humidity combinations and 1's are comfortable.

Any ideas on how I can go about plotting this graph and then finding a best-fit line to predict whether any temp-humidity pair is acceptable?

Comment: What does your 21x16 matrix look like using imagesc? (Assuming that your temperature and humidity data is sorted)

Comment: Assuming there is close to a line dividing the 1s and 0s, then you want to use [Logistic Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)